# Does Dropbox affect Internet line speed?

Tags: internet-connection, performance, dropbox

My Internet speed is awful. Browsing, the works. Does Dropbox affect internet line speed because of the constant updating of the info in your Dropbox?

Comment: In the Dropbox preferences, you can specify upper limits on the upload and download bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

The only time you'll get stress on your link from dropbox is when is actually syncing files.

If you have a lot of dropbox activity (near constant) then it could, but it is difficult to imagine what you could be doing that would make it continually upload.

Comment: If the syncing does cause problems, there are options in preferences to limit the bandwidth usage.

Answer (score 2):

I am an ISP, and I can tell you for a fact that Dropbox can degrade the network performance of any computer on which it is installed. We get complaints about this frequently. When we tell the user to remove Dropbox, and he or she does so, there's a noticeable performance improvement.

It is not clear to us whether the problem results from the software digging itself into the computer's TCP/IP stack, wasting bandwidth, wasting CPU, spying on the user, or all of the above. We do know that removing it solves the problem.

Comment: This reads like a rant. Do you have any evidence?

Comment: I can add an anecdote in support of this - when trying to do a large sync (say to a new computer), my family complains bitterly of wifi slowdowns, streaming problems with movies etc.  I have to pause the dropbox transfer and only run after hours.  Very frustrating when the computer goes to sleep and nothing is transferred.  So, perhaps a rant, but the frustration is justified.

Comment: We presently have this issue on our network and the files being synced are word documents not larger than 2mb. (from accounts and sales)

Answer (score 1):

**Nope**. It only does LAN discovery by default. That's the only traffic I've seen from Dropbox with Wireshark. I guess it also checks the server connection, once in a while. But that's also, just a bit of a traffic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that, by default, Dropbox syncs with the remote server. The LAN sync is just a bonus that can sometimes help reduce the amount of data transferred to/from the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

If you change or move a lot of files around in your Dropbox folder it can cause both bandwidth use and just general slowing of a computer. I saw this in reorganizing a bunch of folders.  Mind you, I just moved things and did not delete or add files. However Dropbox treats a move as a delete and then an add of a new file, so all the computers sync'd to my Dropbox account began doing downloads of thousands of files because I rearranged a few folders. This bogged down one of my computers over a full day.

If you also have one of Dropbox's larger service plans, the service plan can actually be bigger than the free space on your computer. I've seen this as well as a client suddenly uploaded some very large files to shared folder and basically locked two of my computers.